# For loop to run predict()

Tags: r, loops, for-loop

This is my current code:

```
for(i in 1:64){ predict(s3, newdata = m2016[i,]) }
```

s3 is the linear model I am using and each of the 64 rows m2016 contains a data frame which I would like to use here.

The problem is, when I run this code, nothing appears. Even if I add the paste() command surrounding the predict command, nothing appears.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What do you want to do with the result of `predict`? print it to the screen - wrap it in `print(...)`, assign it to a variable, use `p <- predict( )`.

Comment: Okay, thanks. I see how I can print out everything now. How about if I wanted to plot each value of p on the y axis and each i on the x axis?

Comment: then you'd use your favourite/most appropriate plotting package to plot your values...

Comment: predict is vectorized, meaning you don't need to iterate through each row of m2016, a simple `predict(s3, newdata = m2016)` will give you all 64 predicted values back.

Comment: If `m2016` is a matrix of dataframes then that's possible, but that's a rather unusual R structure. What does `dim(m2016`) return? What is the output of `terms(s3)`?

Comment: Chase gave the answer I wanted here. and I can just add plot() to that function. Thanks.